# command working in command line but not thru script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
cat test.txt
#this is comment
line 1
line 2
#this is comment at line 3
line4
```

script:

```
result=`awk '/^#.*/ { print }' test.txt `

for x in $result
do
echo x
done
```

expected output:

```
#this is comment
#this is comment at line 3
```

getting output:

```
#this
is
comment
#this
is
comment
at
line
3
```

but when i execute this command `awk '/^#.*/ { print }' test.txt`, 
i get expected result. 
I am putting this in loop because I need to capture each comment one at a time, not all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `for x in $result` will loop through each *word* in `$result` - that's what `for` is meant to do.

Try this instead:

```
echo "$result" | while read x; do
    echo "$x"
done
```

`read` will take one line at a time, which is what you need here.

Comment: With bash, you can use a here-string: `while read line; ...; done <<< "$result"`. Using a pipeline puts the while loop in a subshell that may have undesirable side-effects.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not the `awk` part, but is the `for` part.  When you do

```
for x in yes no maybe why not
do
   echo x
done
```

You'll get

```
yes
no
maybe
why
not
```

That is, the list that `for` is looping over is automatically space-delimited.

One fix, I suppose, is to wrap the comments in quotes; then `for` will treat each quoted comment as a single item.  legoscia's fix (using `read` in a while loop) seems even better to me.